# Ripgrep default search

Tags: projectile, ripgrep

I have been using `projectile-ripgrep` for a few months and I'm pretty happy with it. A few days ago I was testing some of is options and the default search for ripgrep (what I see in the minibuffer) changed from:

```
[my-project] Ripgrep search for (default my_function):
```

to:

```
[my-project] Ripgrep search for: my_function
```

I find it a bit annoying since I like how it used to *suggest* the search (same as when you do a `query-replace`), meaning that if I did not enter any character, it would search the *suggested* term. Now that term is already part of the input, so if I want to search for something else I have to delete it first.

I am not sure how I changed this and I am not able to set it back to how it was. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured out why this is happening to your environment after reading your comments below.

There are two `projectile-ripgrep` ([package projectile](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile/blob/d1daf274e8ca2eb0f20475b8f314bb955167c6a1/projectile.el#L3400) & [package projectile-ripgrep](https://github.com/nlamirault/ripgrep.el/blob/40e871dcc4519a70981e9f28acea304692a60978/projectile-ripgrep.el#L45)). Whichever is loaded second in order is being used, hence the different behavior on your machine.

---

Original answer:

<strike>(I don't have enough reputation to add a comment.)</strike>

Which version of `projectile` are you using? Are we looking at the same code [here](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile/blob/d1daf274e8ca2eb0f20475b8f314bb955167c6a1/projectile.el#L3192)?

If so, could you try playing around with the following expression and see what happens? (Both in your current settings and `emacs -Q`)

```
 (read-string (format "%s%s: " "prefix " "(default label)") nil nil "default retval")
```

Comment: According to my `package-list-packages`: `projectile: 20200710.947` and `projectile-ripgrep 20180914.1500`. So I think it is updated and we should be looking at the same code. If I `eval-region` that expression, I get: `prefix (default label):` which seems the expected result.

Comment: Ok, just in case, I updated all my packages (including `projectile` up to `20201030.1132`)  and it went back to the previous way  I'm still not sure why it changed before.

Comment: I restarted emacs to check if it would stay the same and no, it is sticking with the search without default. So it looks like it might be something in my `.emacs`, but I am not sure what.

Comment: Perhaps you could try stepping through the code using Edebug and see what happens.

Comment: @makeMonday I think I've figured out what's going on here. I'll rewrite the answer.

Comment: Yay! You're right, I actually removed `projectile-ripgrep` from my packages and `.emacs`, reloaded everything and it is working as expected :) Thanks!